# Is it possible to turn a 2d scatter plot into 3d by including frequency in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, data-analysis, scatter3d

xI have two fields I'm comparing.  Both of them are nominals, with only ones and zeros.  Men and women, and default and no default (plus lots more data in a similar format).  If you put it into a scatter plot you only get four dots because of course all those scenarios happen, but the question is how many times does it happen in each case.  It would be amazing if I could see it by flipping it on its side and see the frequency of how many times each dot hits one of those four points.

for example:

```
x = [1,0,0,0,...1,1,0,1]
y = [0,1,1,0,...1,0,1,0]
```

I have the code:

```
def scatterPlot3dFields():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(x, y, ???)
    plt.show()
```

But I have no idea what to put in the z axis to make this happen.  Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [`np.histogram2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html), which is a great method for determining the frequency (in the sense of number of occurences) for 2-dimensional data. You could try something like:

```
import numpy as np

# data of 1s and 0s
n_points = 100
x = np.random.randint(2, size=n_points) # ([1, 0, 1, ... , 0, 0, 1])
y = np.random.randint(2, size=n_points) # ([0, 1, 1, ... , 1, 0, 1])

H, xedges, yedges  = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=2)
# H = frequency from the four points (0, 0), (0,1), (1,0), and (1,1)
# H = ([21, 26], [32, 21]]) for example (must sum to n_points (100))
```

It also sounds like you want to visualize the frequency. To do so, you can use a 3D bar graph ([`bar3d`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d)). Check out this [matplotlib example code](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html).